# SQL statement using case, like, and having

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using an Oracle based system.

How do you use like, having, and a case statement together?

I am basically trying to list all of the unique individuals that are found in a transactional table that have more than 4 "Class A" transactions, or more than 1 "Class B" transactions. The reason why I want to use `like` is because the only way to diferentiate between transaction classes is by using a `like` statement in the transaction type column.

For example, there are many transaction types, but only "Class A" have `'%ABC%'` as part of their transaction type, and "Class B" are all the other types that do not have `'%ABC%'` in their transaction type column.

So again, I want my query to return only the indiv ids that have more than 4 "Class A" Transactions, or 1 "Class B" transaction.

here is what I have so far:

```
select tt.indiv_id, count(*) from transactiontable tt
group by tt.indiv_id
case when tt.tran_type like '%ABC'
having count(*) > 4
else
having count(*)>1.
```

I have searched a good bit on the site and I have not found an example using all of these functions together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tt.indiv_id, 
    count(case when tt.tran_type like '%ABC' then 1 end) as ClassACount,
    count(case when tt.tran_type not like '%ABC' then 1 end) as ClassBCount
from transactiontable tt
group by tt.indiv_id
having count(case when tt.tran_type like '%ABC' then 1 end) > 4
    or count(case when tt.tran_type not like '%ABC' then 1 end) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will check this one as well! This site has so many helpful users!

Comment: After trying it in a real-world scenario, this answer worked best. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select tt.indiv_id, count(*) 
from transactiontable tt  
group by tt.indiv_id, tt.tran_type
having count(*) > case when tt.tran_type like '%ABC' then 4 else 1 end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! I will try this and let you know the results immediately.

Comment: Wow you rock! this worked perfectly! if for some reason I have trouble with it again I will comment here again. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is close.  You want to keep track of each transaction type separately in the having clause:

```
select tt.indiv_id, count(*)
from transactiontable tt
group by tt.indiv_id
having sum(case when tt.tran_type like '%ABC%' then 1 else 0 end) > 4 or
       sum(case when tt.tran_type not like '%ABC%' then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

Comment: For the count(*) in the question, do you want all transactions or only the ones triggering the HAVING clause.  This version returns the count of all transactions.  The other two answers return the count of just one type.

Comment: only the ones triggering the having clause, this answer works really well as well. I hate to pick a checkmark because they are all valid, and furthermore if something does not work its probably my fault since I might have coded something wrong somewhere. Still, this answer is very valid.